# Comparing two dbo tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, but I essentially would like to do the following.

I have two tables, the key is a 'hostname' with various columns.

Table1 = 'hostnames' and 'msofficeversions' columns
Table2 = 'hostnames' and 'lastlogon' columns.

I need table1 to filter whatever version of msoffice  query, BUT also I need table1 to compare hostnames on table2 and produce the 'lastlogon' time from table2. All this is to come out in one table.

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by filter, but try this out:

```
select t1.hostname, t1.msofficeversions, t2.lastlogon 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.hostname = t2.hostname
where t1.msofficeversions = '2010'
```